# Contents from url to string

Tags: objective-c, nsurl, url-encoding

```
NSString *urlAddress = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.domain.com?input=%@",[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text];
NSURL *myUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlAddress stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSString *openURL = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:myUrl encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
NSLog(@"%@",openURL);
```

`openUrl` is always returning `(null)`, probably because of the encoding, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: The method has a means of giving you errors and your not using it `error:NULL];`, check this first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSError *error;
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.domain.com?input=%@", stringVariable];
NSURL *urlAdress = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSString *urlContent = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:urlAdress encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
NSLog(@"%@", urlContent);
```

This works fine, the problem was an failing internet connection.

Answer (score 1):

Double check these three things:

- Check that the URL which you are pointing to is a valid URL. The `null` value could be a result of an invalid URL.
- Catch the `NSError` which the `stringWithContentsOfURL` throws. That will give you some insight on what is wrong.
- Like you suspect, try changing the string encoding.